# Can something be done about my mouse or buying a new one is the only option?

Tags: mouse

As soon as I connect my mouse, it shows this error:

`USB device not recognised. The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it.`

I updated the driver software and it showed that the best driver software is already there. When I view properties it shows an error (Code 43).

This is the properties screen with the error:

[image: This is the properties screen with the error]

Comment: does it work on other computers / operating systems ?

Comment: No it isn't working on another laptop with same OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the on exclamation mark, uninstall and reboot.  If you plug another USB stick to the port and it work.  That port is good.  If you take the not working mouse to another PC and it don't work, get another mouse.